# Is there any efficient solution/approach?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, ado.net

I am creating a tool that takes two databases as its input, compares tables and show "only the differences in data" among tables.

For example,
Source Database-  Person, Orders (Two Tables)
Destination Database-   Person, Orders (Two Tables)

Now, my application compares Person in source database with the Person in Destination database and display only those records that are in the source Person and not in destination Person.

Here is my approach-

1. Load both the databases into two DataSet (source DataSet,
   destinatioin DataSet).
2. Compare both the tables row by row.
3. And if any changes found found like row in source Person that are not in destination Person then insert these row into destination Person.

My question: Is there any better/efficient way to achieve this?

Iterating over entire databases is least efficient solution.

Comment: do you want to treat these 2 input databases as "master database" and "slave database" (everything in master must be in slave) ?

Comment: No. The application must also list all the rows that are in the destination Person and not in source Person.

Comment: @Jossef Harush It compares both tables source Person and destination Person. On left side it will display all the rows that are in source Person and not in destination Person (means, new rows). On right side it displays all the rows that are in destination Person and not in source Person (mean, old rows).

Comment: seems like best practice to use the [Replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) feature (if licensed)

Comment: Do you control the database structure or those are 3rd party products?

Comment: @Edgars I control the database structure. For comparison, the schema of both databases must be same.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually best to push work into the database. Generate a `FULL OUTER JOIN` query for each pair of tables to compute the differences on the server. This will be *by far* faster than transferring all data to the client.

In particular datatables etc. are not very efficient.

A different approach is the request the rows sorted and perform a merge join in-memory on the two result streams. You can find sample code for how to merge two sorted streams on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you want to do as much processing in the databases as possible.  This is particularly true for processing that is going to read the entire contents of a table.  Relational databases are designed for this type of processing.

If both databases are on the same server, then you might have a query like this to get person records in the source that are not in the destination:

```
select s.*
from source..person
except
select d.*
from destination..person;
```

What are the advantages of this approach?

- SQL Server can run the queries using multiple threads.
- SQL Server can make use of indexes (although that might not be appropriate for this particular query).
- SQL Server only returns the data that is needed by the application.

If they are not on the same server, than you can use a linked server to connect the servers.  The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) is a good place to understand how to use linked servers.  This will even work if the servers use different databases.